# Assert that method does not throw an exception with AssertJ 1.x soft assertions

Tags: java, junit, assertj

I would like to test that a particular method can handle a bunch of strings without an exception. Therefore, I would like to use AssertJ's [soft assertions](http://joel-costigliola.github.io/assertj/assertj-core-features-highlight.html#soft-assertions), something like:

```
SoftAssertion softly = new SoftAssertion();

for (String s : strings) {
    Foo foo = new Foo();

    try {
        foo.bar(s);
        // Mark soft assertion passed.
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // Mark soft assertion failed.
    }
}

softly.assertAll();
```

Unfortunately, I have to stick to AssertJ 1.x respectively Java 6, so I cannot take advantage of this:

```
assertThatCode(() -> {
    // code that should throw an exception
    ...
}).doesNotThrowAnyException();
```

Is there a way do this with AssertJ (or JUnit)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would say it's not a good practice to have a loop in the test code.

If code you run inside a test throws an exception - it fails the test.
My suggestion would be to use a Parameterized runner for JUnit (shipped with the library).

Example from official JUnit 4 documentation:

```
import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collection;

import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.junit.runners.Parameterized;
import org.junit.runners.Parameterized.Parameters;

@RunWith(Parameterized.class)
public class FibonacciTest {
    @Parameters
    public static Collection<Object[]> data() {
        return Arrays.asList(new Object[][] {     
                 { 0, 0 }, { 1, 1 }, { 2, 1 }, { 3, 2 }, { 4, 3 }, { 5, 5 }, { 6, 8 }  
           });
    }

    private int fInput;

    private int fExpected;

    public FibonacciTest(int input, int expected) {
        fInput= input;
        fExpected= expected;
    }

    @Test
    public void test() {
        // Basically any code can be executed here
        assertEquals(fExpected, Fibonacci.compute(fInput));
    }
}

public class Fibonacci {
    public static int compute(int n) {
        int result = 0;

        if (n <= 1) { 
            result = n; 
        } else { 
            result = compute(n - 1) + compute(n - 2); 
        }

        return result;
    }
}
```

Comment: If you post the example instead the link I will up vote, the answer is good, but links on time will break and further readers won't be able to see then

Comment: Now it is a complete answer, great job, thank you for sharing knowledge